# Remove custom component from component menu

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

When I create custom components and I need to add a menu type to the site part I've always followed the [tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_a_menu_type_to_the_site_part) on how to do this. In other words I create the default.xml in the view and I now can assign my component to a menu. i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
        <message>
            <![CDATA[COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC]]>
        </message>
    </layout>
</metadata>
```

The problem I have is that this also creates a label under Components in the Administrator interface. Because I have so many custom components my Components menu in the Administrator is getting quite long. It is useless for me to have these components listed in the Administrator interface as I have no extra configuration for these components.

Can I still have my components show up as a menu type but NOT have it show up in the Components menu of the Administrator panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible by using the API. But you can always disable menu items manually after installation. The administration panel is in fact just a mod_menu module which shows the administration menu, which is hidden in your menu management.

Another way would be to use a different module or alternative layout for mod_menu to exclude specific items.

Hint: If you want to know what happens during installation, look into

```
libraries/cms/installer/adapter/component.php - line 1209 and following
```